# Hibernate-db events

Tags: database, hibernate, events

i am using hibernate to access database.and i am using hibernate query caching as only 3 queries are made in 95% case.Now once initialized update operation on db is very rare.So i want to expire the cache only when any insert/update/delete etc not-read-only operations are done on db.is it possible with hibernate?if yes how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "insert/update/delete [...] operations" done through Hibernate?  If so, that is already the case.

Or do you mean "insert/update/delete [...] operations" done to the database outside of Hibernate's knowledge?  In that case, there is not any way for Hibernate to know that. You would need to tell Hibernate that.  There are a number of approaches to this.  The simplest is to evict the query cache regions:

```
sessionFactory.getCache().evictDefaultQueryRegion()
```

or

```
sessionFactory.getCache().evictQueryRegion( "region-name-you-supplied-to-Query" )
```

or

```
sessionFactory.getCache().evictQueryRegions()
```